# open source swing based application that employs good practices

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to learn swing and I was thinking you guys may know a really good swing based open source application that I could study and inspire from. I'm looking for something that has a real world use, not just some concepts explained (like examples in most books and tutorials).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly less well-known than some of the other projects mentioned here, but have a look at [GoGrinder](http://gogrinder.sourceforge.net/).  The code is well written and documented.

It might also be a good idea to look for something that you'll actually use.  I find it easier to read the source of applications that I'm familiar with from using them.

Comment: Nice suggestion Bill. This project I might actually understand! :)

Comment: GoGrinder is GPL so you cannot reuse the code unless your application is GPL tool

Comment: @Anthony: So?  He's asking for code to look at and learn from.  You're free to use it for that.

Comment: Yes but if he sees an useful class/method he cannot reuse the code.

Comment: @Anthony: GoGrinder isn't a library.  It's a swing application for learning Go problems.  Bogdan is trying to learn swing, not looking for libraries of useful code to reuse.

Answer (score 4):

In the same spirit as the answer suggesting to check NetBeans, I would suggest to get the sources of [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition and IntelliJ Platform](http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=summary) from their git repository. At some point, IDEA was IMO a state of the art Swing application (fast, responsive, not ugly, nice user experience, etc).

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I'll take a look at IDEA too. Although I'm a little overwhelmed with the size of these gigantic products (NB included) :)

Comment: @Bogdan While projects like NetBeans and IntelliJ IDEA do fit as answers to this question, I agree they might not be simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could have a look at the open source [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/). It is huge, but it is using Swing intensively and is well designed and documented. Moreover, it is also a generic platform to build modular GUI applications.

Comment: I'm downloading now. I've been using NB for a while, but never thought of looking at its source code :D. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

[*The Swing Tutorial*](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) is filled with excellent code, and the Swing code itself is available for study in most IDEs.

Comment: Yes, I know about Swing Tutorial. It is excellent for learning different topics about the framework. What I'm looking for is seeing how ppl use swing in real life! How do they deal with threading, database access, how are they organizing their increasing code base - stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org) is a programmer's text editor that I wrote some plugins for a few years ago.  Partially due to the plugin system, the code is well documented, and after having been in development for many years is generally very high quality.

Comment: I've looked a little through jEdit's source and one thing I really like it's the comment system. I like it so much that I started using in  my own projects; And I found a plugin for eclipse (Coffe Bytes Code Folding) which folds the comments, just like jEdit :D

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the  [jgoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) examples. They are not plain swing though, and I don't know the license.

Comment: Well, applications from that link don't seem to have any source code available...